# How to Save base64 encoded image into MYSQL database using API in android

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap

Variable within the `onActivityResult` method and `bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap)` method variables **cant be access outside**,
It storing **null value** in Mysql database while passing through url in android.

**For Example**: In below code I am storing encoded image base64String in encoderes.
But while try to access from outside the method and while passing the encoded String through url. 
It saves as **null** in database.

```
public String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
encoderes = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
encodedImage.setImgStr(encoderes);
encodestr.setText(encoderes);

return encoderes; }
```

**Encode code snippet**

```
   @Override 
   public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
   data)
   {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    bitmapToBase64(bmap);} else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
    bitmapToBase64(bmap);

    //Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

} }                                                                    
public String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
encoderes = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
encodedImage.setImgStr(encoderes);
encodestr.setText(encoderes);

return encoderes; }
```

Comment: Why not save it as blob? No increase in size and better performance compared to b64.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method :

```
public static String convertToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.setDensity(IMAGE_DENSITY);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        setDpiInfo(byteArray, IMAGE_DENSITY);
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
```

Comment: it storing null value in mysql database..?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    // get the base 64 string
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return imgString;
}
```

*Use returened value to send to server*

Comment: it storing null value in mysql database..?